# GCP Functions keeps trying until data is fetched

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, async-await, google-cloud-functions

Below is works in local machine, but when deployed as GCP function. Instead of waiting for await , keeps invoking new instance until data is obtained.

any help to solve this is much appreciated, as this is spamming calls and increasing the load.

```
var callAI = async function callAI (userPrompt)
{
  try {
  console.log("user prompt",userPrompt)
  const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
   model: "gpt-4",
   messages: [{role: "user", content: userPrompt}]
  });

  output = response.data.choices[0].message
  console.log("Data to be passed",output)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("encountered error with callAI function")
    res.status(200).send(failedMessage);
  }
  res.status(200).send(output);
}
```

Attached image if you notice function does not wait for the call to complete but keeps invoking again and again until the data is received and this is spamming the users.

Simple query like "hello" works fine as this does not take more than a second. I see this issue where there a wait of more than 30 seconds and till now no solution has been found

[image: GCP function execution]
Any help here is much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps invoking new instance"?  What exactly are you observing?  What is `xxxxx`?  Why are you using `new Promise` along with `await`?  You shouldn't need `new Promise` at all if you are able to use async/await.  Please edit the question to be more clear what the problem is.

Comment: @DougStevenson - Added more details, hope you can help me to solve this

Comment: Those are just empty log lines.  They aren't saying that the function is executed again. Nothing that you show here indicates what would be logging an empty line.

Comment: @DougStevenson - not sure what you mean as empty . As the screenshot says "function execution started" clearly which is post the console of "user prompt". Meaning when  function hits the await call. Instead of waiting, new instance is created. Image is showing the same very clearly